# How to get the data that was being sent from controller to json?

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dom-events

I'm trying to convert this fullcalendar code from using entity framework to using Sql commands.

This is the **ORIGINAL** code :

1.JS Code

```
        var events = [];
        var selectedEvent = null;
        FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
        function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
            events = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/home/GetEvents",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        events.push({
                            eventID: v.EventID,
                            title: v.Subject,
                            description: v.Description,
                            start: moment(v.Start),
                            end: v.End != null ? moment(v.End) : null,
                            color: v.ThemeColor,
                            allDay: v.IsFullDay
                        });
                    })
```

2.ASP.Net Code (From HomeController)

```
    public JsonResult GetEvents()
    {
        using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
        {
            var events = dc.Events.ToList();
            return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
        }
    }
```

This is the **MY CONVERTED** code :

1.JS Code

```
    var events = [];
    var selectedEvent = null;
    FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
    function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
        events = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Dashboard/GetEvents",
            success: function (Data) {
                $.each(Data, function (i, v) {
                        events.push({
                        eventID: v.EventID,
                        title: v.Subject,
                        description: v.Description,
                        start: moment(v.Start, ["YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"]),
                        end: v.End != null ? moment(v.End, ["YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"]) : null,
                        color: v.ThemeColor,
                        allDay: v.IsFullDay
                    });
                });
                GenerateCalender(events);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("It Failed");

            }
        })
    }
```

2.ASP.Net Code (From DashboardController)

```
    public JsonResult GetEvents()
    {
        
        DataTable dtblSchedules = new DataTable("Schedule");
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Schedule", sqlCon);
            sqlDa.Fill(dtblSchedules);
            List<Schedules> scheduleList = new List<Schedules>();
            for (int i = 0; i < dtblSchedules.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Schedules schedulesModel = new Schedules();
                schedulesModel.EventID = Convert.ToInt32(dtblSchedules.Rows[i]["ScheduleId"]);
                schedulesModel.Subject = dtblSchedules.Rows[i]["Subject"].ToString();
                schedulesModel.Description = dtblSchedules.Rows[i]["Description"].ToString();
                schedulesModel.Start = dtblSchedules.Rows[i]["Start_time"].ToString();
                schedulesModel.End = dtblSchedules.Rows[i]["End_time"].ToString();
                schedulesModel.ThemeColor = dtblSchedules.Rows[i]["Theme"].ToString();
                schedulesModel.IsFullday = dtblSchedules.Rows[i]["Full_day"].ToString();
                scheduleList.Add(schedulesModel);
            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = scheduleList, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
        }
    }
```

So what I'm trying to do is change the usage from database entities to SQL commands cause i want to use the database from my SQL server.I kept the way the original code works in that the data returned is in **list** but I didn't received any data in the view's JS CODE but the `jsonrequestbehavior` was received.

In the end,the calendar shows but there is no event that is being shown,even though there is a data on my database.I tried using a dummy data by filling the eventID,title,etc and it showed on my calendar.**So the problem is how do I get the data from my database to the JS events ? Please help me!**

This is the result when I used dummy data :
[The events are shown on the calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBLWV.png)

2 events were shown ,I think this is because there are 2 data from my database rn.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the JSON maxJsonLengthin web config.

```
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

https://forums.asp.net/t/1962449.aspx?JSON+Maximum+length+problem+with+ASP+NET

Comment: I have tried this,but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Look at the  Data.Data.v.EventID ,  Data.Data.v.Subject. Check the  ' Data '

Comment: try $.each(Data.Data, function (i, v)

Comment: 1.The Data in both original and converted is a parameter:any.
2.I tried the next comment and it failed too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those who have contribute to answer this question.I have found a way to convert the code using the little knowledge that I have on ASP.NET MVC and Javascript.

This is how I solved it:

Using the model that I have created,I changed the way we get the data from the database. Below is the code that I used right now to fetch the data from my database :

```
var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var events = [];
var selectedEvent = null;
FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {

   @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++) {
       @: events.push({ eventID: @Model.Rows[i][0], title: "@Model.Rows[i][1]", description:"@Model.Rows[i][2]" , start: "@Convert.ToDateTime(Model.Rows[i][3]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")", end:"@Convert.ToDateTime(Model.Rows[i][4]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")", color: "@Model.Rows[i][5]", allDay: "@Model.Rows[i][6]", });
   }
   GenerateCalender(events);
}
```

I used the datatable that was sent back along with the view as my way to get the data for my array.